# Adding elements in subsets of components of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have six tables of data say

```
t1 = {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
t2 = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}};
t3 = {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}};
t4 = {{1, 5}, {2, 8}, {3, 9}};
t5 = {{1, 8}, {2, 1}, {3, 8}};
t6 = {{1, 9}, {2, 5}, {3, 3}};
```

I want to add all data such that first data in the brace remains same but the second data are added up.

For an example:

```
tsum1 = {{1,31},{2,34},{3,32}};
```

How can I do it in *Mathematica*? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you get `{{1,31},{2,34},{3,32}}`? I get `{{1, 31}, {2, 28}, {3, 32}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the tables and then divide the numbers in the first column by the number of lists you added:

```
MapAt[#/6 &, t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6, {{All, 1}}]
(* {{1, 31}, {2, 28}, {3, 32}} *)
```

`#/6 &` is a function that returns the argument divided by 6, and this function is applied to the first column.

Answer (score 5):

```
t = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}
asc = Association /@ (Rule @@@ # &/@ t)

List@@@Normal@Merge[Total][asc]
```

> `{{1, 31}, {2, 28}, {3, 32}}`

or

```
Transpose@{t[[1, All, 1]], Total@t[[All, All, 2]]}
```

> `{{1, 31}, {2, 28}, {3, 32}}`

or

```
♯0 = {#/6, #2} & @@@ +## & @@ # &;
♯0 @ t
```

> `{{1, 31}, {2, 28}, {3, 32}}`

Answer (score 5):

Basically operationally equivalent to kglr's second option, but sans `Transpose`:

```
With[{d = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}},
 Thread@{First /@ First@d, Last /@ # & /@ d // Total}
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Some approaches:

- for this specific example

  ```
  {#1/6, #2} & @@@ (t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 + t6)
  ```
- using `Sow` and `Reap`:

  ```
  ts = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}
  Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ Join @@ (ts), _, {#1, Total@#2} &][[-1]]
  ```
- using `Association` and `Merge`:

  ```
  ds =Rule @@@ # & /@ ts;
  List @@@ Normal[Merge[ds, Total]]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

May be a little bit hacky, but this seems to work

```
data = ToExpression["t" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[6];
{data[[1, #, 1]], Total[data[[All, #, 2]]]} & /@ Range[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah... that can work.